# How to map a FirestoreStream into a list of objects in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I want to create a stream that will feed data automatically from Firestore to a list.
I just can't seem to get the syntax right.
It must map the stream into a list of ELEVE objects.

```
class FirestoreStream {
  final firestoreStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Stream<List<Eleve>> getLiveUpDate({required String account}) async* {
    yield* firestoreStream
        .collection('familyAccounts')
        .doc(account)
        .collection('listeEleves')
        .doc('mesEleves')
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.data()!
        .map((doc) => Eleve.fromMap(doc)).toList();
  }
}
```

Here is the definition of the class ELEVE :

```
class Eleve {
  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;
    if (runtimeType != other.runtimeType) return false;
    return other is Eleve && other.email == email;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => email.hashCode;

  String classeCode;
  String email;
  String userId;
  DateTime dateAjout;
  String avatar;
  List<ActiviteProf> activites;
  List<DefiProf> defis;
  List<Message> messages;

  Eleve({
    required this.classeCode,
    required this.email,
    required this.userId,
    required this.avatar,
    required this.dateAjout,
    required this.activites,
    required this.defis,
    required this.messages,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {

    return {
      'email': email,
      'classeCode': classeCode,
      'userId': userId,
      'avatar': avatar,
      'dateAjout': dateAjout,
      'messages': messages.map((e) => e.toMap()).toList(),
    };
  }

  factory Eleve.fromMap(Map data) {

    List _messagesMap = data['messages'];

    return Eleve(
      classeCode: data['classeCode'] ?? '',
      email: data['email'] ?? '',
      userId: data['userId'] ?? '',
      avatar: data['avatar'] ?? '',
      dateAjout: data['dateAjout'].toDate(),
      activites: [],
      defis: [],
      messages: _messagesMap.map((e) => Message.fromMap(e)).toList(),
    );
  }
```

The last line :

```
.map((doc) => Eleve.fromMap(doc)).toList();
```

is wrong. I get "The return type 'Eleve' isn't a 'MapEntry<_, _>', as required by the closure's context.".

Any idea what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You are expected a return type of Stream<List> but instead you return Eleve.fromMap(doc)).toList(). So the method is expecting a Stream of List of Eleve but you are returning a List of Eleve.